# Drag and Drop <select> tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jscript

I have 3 select lists and I would like to have items in the select list to be dragged and dropped amongst themselves. Is this possible?

```html
<select id="select1" multiple style="width: 100px; height: 100px">
    <option>Item 1</option>
    <option>Item 2</option>
    <option>Item 3</option>
    <option>Item 4</option>
    <option>Item 5</option>
</select>

<select id="select2" multiple style="width: 100px; height: 100px">
</select>

<select id="select2" multiple style="width: 100px; height: 100px">
</select>
```

Comment: Make custom dropdown, then you can do anything you like with it.

Comment: No, you can't. Even styling a select element is a chore and adding special functionalities is outright impossible. There might be some hope for `<selectmenu>` element but it's not there yet.